# Different meanings of "supported" software

Tags: ambiguity

Let's say I write a computer program for Linux. People pay me, they get this computer program and my support staff will "**support** them" using it.

There is different (well, actually [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions)) different Linux distributions, such as Debian, Ubuntu, Gentoo, et cetera.

- I build and test my software on Debian. I know for a fact that it works, and I will guarantee that. My support staff will help you resolve any kind of problem, even if it means that I have to fix my software. Legal obligations and everything. So, the combination of Ubuntu and my computer program is **supported**. Debian **supports** my computer program.
- I do not test my software on Ubuntu, but due to the similarities between Ubuntu and Debian, I can reasonably assume that it works. So, Ubuntu **supports** my computer program. My support staff will do their best to help you, and we have every expectation that this combination works, but if it comes down to it, we can't guarantee this combination to work.
- Gentoo is very different than Debian, and my software is not expected to work on it. So, Gentoo does not **support** my computer program.

Much appreciated!

The confusion is about the first two scenarios here. What terminology can I use to distinguish the two? Currently, I often end up describing the distinction in a longer sentence, and I would love for there to be a more succinct way to indicate these.

Comment: You may differentiate: *recommended* (Debian), suppported (Ubuntu) and unsupported (Gentoo) environments.

Comment: You should modify the business perspective customers have of your product. 1 - Fully guaranteed support. 2 - Community support. Community support is a mode of support whereby a software producer will depend on the community for a lot of the answers and solution. It is a mode whereby it is understood you are under no liability or obligation to provide that support - except out of good faith and community spirit.

Comment: "... the combination of Ubuntu and my computer program is supported. Debian supports my computer program."  -->  "My program **runs** / **is designed to run** under Ubuntu. My program is supported when **run** under Ubuntu (only)."

Comment: This looks like more of writing advice kind of question, though.

Comment: You have supported "configurations" or "environments" where customers can run your code and expect a concerted effort from you to maintain functionality.  (But, alas, often those environments are only, in truth, "propped up in a few spots" by *their* vendors.)

Comment: The word **support** is often used for all these. The context is expected to make it clear which sense is intended.

Comment: @Graffito, using "supported" for Ubuntu is exactly where the problem lies. This creates the expectation that we will be support it (to the fullest extent, possibly), and that seems incorrect.

Comment: @Kris, this is the best tag I could come up with, but I don't care deeply about my chosen tag.

Comment: @Barmar, I agree that "support" is often used for these, but that's exactly what I try to disambiguate, or: get better language for.

Comment: @BlessedGeek, we're still chewing this all over at my work, but your "Community support" is (so far) the most-liked approach to refer to the "Ubuntu" case. We've been talking (so far) about "Supported" versus "Community support". You might as well type this up as an answer. Not sure though if I can just the answer that I like best (this then slowly becoming a subjective question)?

Answer (score -1):

The second one is called supporting on a "best endeavours" basis.

A slightly lower level would be a "reasonable endeavours" basis.

[This article](http://www.walkermorris.co.uk/best-endeavours-all-reasonable-endeavours-and-reasonable-endeavours) discusses it from a legal perspective.

Comment: After reading the article, I would instead think: the first one is "best ...", the second one "reasonable ...". No?